# Cómo implementar encadenamiento hacia adelante en Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Tengo este código en Prolog, para hacer encadenamiento hacia delante pero tengo este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
> :- op( 800, fx, if). :- op( 700, xfx, then). :- op( 300, xfy, or).  :- op( 200, xfy, and).


    if sala_humeda and cocina_seca
    then fuga_en_bano.
    if sala_humeda and bano_seco
    then problema_en_cocina.

    if ventana_cerrada or no_lluvia
    then no_agua_del_exterior.
    
    if problema_en_cocina and no_agua_del_exterior
    then fuga_en_cocina.
    
    fact(sala_humeda).  
    fact(bano_seco).
    fact(ventana_cerrada).
    
    
    forward :-
    new_derived_fact(P), 
    !,
    write('Nuevo hecho derivado: '), write(P), nl,
    assert(fact(P)),
    forward 
    ;
    write('No se derivaron más hechos.'). 
    
    new_derived_fact(Concl) :-
    if Cond then Concl, % Una regla
    \+ fact(Concl), 
    composed_fact(Cond). 
    
    composed_fact(Cond) :-
    fact(Cond).
    
    composed_fact(Cond1 and Cond2) :-
    composed_fact(Cond1),
    composed_fact(Cond2). 
    
    composed_fact(Cond1 or Cond2) :-
    composed_fact(Cond1)
    ;
    composed_fact(Cond2).
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicar que el hecho `fact/1` es dinámico utilizando la directiva

```
:-dynamic(fact/1).
```

Luego de poner esa directiva puedes realizar la consulta:

```
?- forward.
Nuevo hecho derivado: problema_en_cocina
Nuevo hecho derivado: no_agua_del_exterior
Nuevo hecho derivado: fuga_en_cocina
No se derivaron más hechos.
true.
```